# Using combined models with pagy, getting undefined method 'offset' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I am using pagy. I combined two models into one, and I used pagy on that combined model. I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `offset' for #<Array:0x00007f886f88b3b0>
```

With the last line of the code below highlighted.

My code:

```
@problems = Problem.me_and_friends(current_user)
@activities = Activity.me_and_friends(current_user)
@combine = (@problems + @activities).sort{|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
@pagy, @combined = pagy_countless(@combine, items:100, link_extra: 'class="" style="color:black; margin:3px;"')
```

It worked fine with using pagination on @problems alone.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you call the `(@problems + @activities)`, you transform the `ActiveRecord::Relation` into an `array` (which is also not good because you are loading all the database rows into memory, sorting and then paginating them). Pagy expects an ActiveRecord::Relation to work, hence the error.

You can consider multiple solutions,

- Change your UI to show problems and activities in separate UIs, then you can paginate them separately
- Update your models to store both problems and activities in the same table (maybe just a reference table which points to either a `Problem` or an `Activity`)
- If either of these is not feasible, you can consider rolling out a custom solution for the pagination, but it will be tricky.

---

Update: June 21, 2021

If you are using Rails 6, it introduces the concept of [Delegated Types](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39341) which fits well into this scenario. The example given in the link mentions the issue of pagination across different tables.

Comment: Thank you. This told me what I was trying to do was not possible. I solved it by using {% if ... present? %}. If problem.first_type was there, then that. If problem.second_type is there, then that. This way the two types of posts were shown on the same page, chronologically ordered.

Answer (score 2):

pagy can use arrays, follow these steps to do so

in # config/initializers/pagy.rb
add following line

```
require "pagy/extras/array"
```

then you can use it like this in controller

```
@pagy, @combined = pagy_array(@combine, page: some_page_number,  items:
some_number)
```